# Start auto_increment value not working when populating table with data from another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I want to create a table with data from another table in order to set the id to a certain auto_increment start value.

This is the table I want to populate with data from another table:

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| city      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state_id  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city_slug | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

After executing this query:

```
alter table table_temp auto_increment = 40499;
```

If I do a dummy insert:

```
insert into table_temp (city, state, state_id, city_slug) values (1, 1, 1, 1);
```

It does what it's expected, that is, the id starts with the value 40499

```
select * from table_temp;

+-------+------+-------+----------+-----------+
| id    | city | state | state_id | city_slug |
+-------+------+-------+----------+-----------+
| 40499 | 1    | 1     |        1 | 1         |
+-------+------+-------+----------+-----------+
```

After truncate the table and execute again the alter table query for auto_increment, I try to populate the same table with data from another table:

```
insert into table_temp (city, state, state_id, city_slug) select city, state, state_id, city_slug from final_location;
```

However the id starts with a default id value of 1:

```
select * from table_temp limit 10;

+----+---------+---------+----------+-------------------+
| id | city    | state   | state_id | city_slug         |
+----+---------+---------+----------+-------------------+
|  1 | Abatiá  | Paraná  |      242 | all-cidade-abatia |
+----+---------+---------+----------+-------------------+
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: are you working on **MySQL** ?

Comment: Works for me as expected. see my sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a59d2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found what was wrong, after truncating the table it seems to loose reference of the auto_increment start value. I had to execute again the alter table query in order to set the auto_increment value properly again:

```
alter table table_temp auto_increment = 40499;
```